# remove all elements within sublists that are at a specific index - python 2

Tags: python, list

I have a nested list, and I'd like to remove the 2nd element for all the sublists throughtout the list.

The list is as fallows,

```
A=[[[a, b], [c, d], [g, h]]
   [[e, f], [g, h], [t, f]]]
```

Id like to remove the i[1] elements from each sublist within A to get this result,

```
A=[[[a, b],[g, h]]
   [[e, f], [t, f]]]
```

Ive tried doing `A.remove(A[i][1])` but it ends in a "list indices must be integers, not list' error. Any input on how to do this would be a help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple for loop can solve your problem:

```
A=[[['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['g', 'h']],
   [['e', 'f'], ['g', 'h'], ['t', 'f']]]

for l in A:
    l.pop(1)

# A == [[['a', 'b'], ['g', 'h']],
#       [['e', 'f'], ['t', 'f']]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension which is the 'pythonic' way of doing these things:

```
A=[[['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['g', 'h']],
   [['e', 'f'], ['g', 'h'], ['t', 'f']]]

[inner.pop(1) for inner in A]
```

This is equivalent to for loop. Pop removes an element at the index and Python starts with index 0 so index 1 is the second element.

Comment: This won't work because `A = [...]` will assign A to the list comprehension

Answer (score 0):

I think mutating the list is not the best option in general. Most python code you'll find will prefer to return a modified list instead. For example:

```py
A = [[l[0], *l[2:]] for l in A]
```

The advantage here is that you don't risk any side effect:

```py
A = [
    [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['g', 'h']],
    [['e', 'f'], ['g', 'h'], ['t', 'f']],
]

B = A
A = [[l[0], *l[2:]] for l in A]

print(B)
```

Would still output the original list:

```py
[[['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['g', 'h']], [['e', 'f'], ['g', 'h'], ['t', 'f']]]
```

Whereas if you mutate `A`:

```py
for l in A:
    l.pop(1)

print(B)
```

This would output:

```py
[[['a', 'b'], ['g', 'h']], [['e', 'f'], ['t', 'f']]]
```

This is not always true, but unless you have a good reason to, don't use mutations.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe in using `for loops` for list manipulation. You can use `map` and `lambda` to apply a transformation to all list items. To keep only the first and third columns you can do:

```
[*map(lambda x: (x[0], x[2]), A)]
```

or

```
list(map(lambda a, b, c: (a, c), *zip(*A)))
```

They both yield:

```
[(['a', 'b'], ['g', 'h']), (['e', 'f'], ['t', 'f'])]
```